# Filtering out with Datatable.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying to filter out some information from my table generated using datatable.net

I'm using the following code after the table is initiated:

```
var filteredData = testTable
   .column( 2 )
   .data()
   .filter( function ( value, index ) {
   return value = 'Product A' ? true : false;
} );
```

No change is apply to my table nor any js error is flag...

Anyone has an idea?
Thanks, Crak.

Comment: What version of datatables are you using? Also, for comparison you should use `==` instead of `=`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick answer, I'm using the latest one: 1.10.4  I tried using == instead of = whith no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using version 1.10 of datatables, you can use the [`.column().search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29.search%28%29) function to filter a table based on column values. It must be used in conjunction with [`.draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) to update the table:

```
testTable.column(2).search('Product A').draw();
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wbh4n61/

Also see Datatables Example: http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

---

**Update:**

In order to do a negative filter, you could use regex. The 2nd parameter of `.search()` is a boolean indicating whether or not the first parameter should be treated like regex.

The following code will retrieve all rows that do not start with "Product A":

```
testTable.column(2).search("^(?!(?:Product A))", true).draw();
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wbh4n61/1/

Comment: Actually I want to filter out from my list Product A not displaying only Product A.

Comment: @user1064038 According to [this conversation](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3088/negative-filters-ie-how-do-you-search-for-cells-that-do-not-match-a-string), you can use fnFilter with regex to accomplish a negative filter.

Comment: Unfortunately, the fnFilter is no more available in the latest version. :(

Comment: @user1064038 I updated the answer. Unfortunately I'm not a master at regex, but hopefully it helps with your purposes!